# How to update nginx via Chef

Tags: nginx, chef

I am a developer who recently inherited our previous devops person's chef setup. I'm running Chef 10 server and have realized that the nginx cookbook from opscode still uses nginx version 1.2.6. Since there are many security patches that have been released I'd like to move to 1.4.1 and feel that Chef should make this very easy. However it has proven to be nightmarish.

My first thought was to simply make the nginx cookbook "custom" and change the `default['nginx']['version']` attribute to 1.4.1, upload the cookbook and converge a testing server. I watched it fetch the new version of the cookbook (I remembered to update the metadata), and promptly ignore it as it continued using 1.2.6.

Then I thought I should override attributes in the role I am using (rails_tier_web is the name of the role). Speaking with a more experienced Chef person he cautioned against it since roles cannot be versioned and pinned the way cookbooks can. However reading the documentation for the cookbook, they tell you to use the override attributes in your role so that's what I've done:

`override_attributes(
  'nginx' => {
    'source' => {
      'version' => '1.4.1',
      'prefix' => '/opt/nginx-1.4.1'
    },
    'version' => '1.4.1'
  }
)`

However when I converge I am still seeing traces of 1.2.6 show up in the log output.

```
[2013-07-15T18:52:03-04:00] INFO: Processing remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.6.tar.gz] action create (nginx::source line 56)
[2013-07-15T18:52:05-04:00] INFO: remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.6.tar.gz] updated
```

and then right after that...

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130715-4790-1m689ee" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /tmp/chef-script20130715-4790-1m689ee: line 2: cd: nginx-1.4.1: No such file or directory
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130715-4790-1m689ee" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130715-4790-1m689ee" returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb

 84: bash "compile_nginx_source" do
 85:   cwd ::File.dirname(src_filepath)
 86:   code <<-EOH
 87:     tar zxf #{::File.basename(src_filepath)} -C #{::File.dirname(src_filepath)} &&
 88:     cd nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']} &&
 89:     ./configure #{node.run_state['nginx_configure_flags'].join(" ")} &&
 90:     make && make install
 91:   EOH
 92:
 93:   not_if do
 94:     nginx_force_recompile == false &&
 95:       node.automatic_attrs['nginx'] &&
 96:       node.automatic_attrs['nginx']['version'] == node['nginx']['source']['version'] &&
 97:       node.automatic_attrs['nginx']['configure_arguments'].sort == configure_flags.sort
 98:   end
 99:
100:   notifies :restart, "service[nginx]"
101: end
102:

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb:84:in `from_file'

bash("compile_nginx_source") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  command "\"bash\"  \"/tmp/chef-script20130715-4790-1m689ee\""
  backup 5
  cwd "/var/chef/cache"
  returns 0
  code "    tar zxf nginx-1.4.1.tar.gz -C /var/chef/cache &&\n    cd nginx-1.4.1 &&\n    ./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx-1.2.6 --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module &&\n    make && make install\n"
  interpreter "bash"
  cookbook_name "nginx"
  recipe_name "source"
  not_if { #code block }
end
```

I am really at wits end because I was hoping I could just override a version attribute and have it all fall into place. Obviously that is not the case thus far and I really don't want to have to do manual patching and/or editing of node objects if I can help it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste your `recipes/source.rb`? Seems to me that you're installing from source. am I right?

Also, take a look at this line on your attributes/default.rb:

`default['nginx']['install_method'] = 'package'`

I'm using the line above to install nginx 1.4.0